# Python gmaps package, marker layer not working

Tags: python, google-maps, visual-studio-code, anaconda, jupyter

I'm using the Jupyter Notebook extension for VSCode (Python 3.10.11 on MacOS). I can run identical code using the 'heatmap_layer' instead and it runs fine. I'm not sure why this doesn't work. This error is returned:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 17
     15 fig = gmaps.figure()
     16 # create the markers layer
---> 17 markers = gmaps.marker_layer(locations)
     18 # add the markers layer to the map
     19 fig.add_layer(markers)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gmaps/marker.py:553, in marker_layer(locations, hover_text, label, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    485 @doc_subst(_doc_snippets)
    486 def marker_layer(
    487         locations, hover_text='', label='',
    488         info_box_content=None, display_info_box=None):
    489     """
    490     Marker layer
    491 
   (...)
    551         A :class:`gmaps.Markers` instance.
    552     """
--> 553     marker_options = _marker_layer_options(
    554         locations, hover_text, label, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    555     markers = [Marker(**option) for option in marker_options]
    556     return Markers(markers=markers)
...
     39         isinstance(elem, string_types) or
---> 40         not isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable)
     41     )

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

My code:

```
# import the gmaps package and input my API key
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key="****")

# list of latitudes and longitudes to be put onto the map
locations = [
(-34.0, -59.166672),
(-32.23333, -64.433327),
(40.166672, 44.133331),
(51.216671, 5.0833302),
(51.333328, 4.25)
]

# create the initial map
fig = gmaps.figure()

# create the markers layer
markers = gmaps.marker_layer(locations)

# add the markers layer to the map
fig.add_layer(markers)

# display the final map
fig
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the brackets in `locations`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.10.11, escaping the brackets in locations was a typo in StackOverflow, just posted the full error text, sorry if the formatting is poor.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no (*or no more?*) `collections.Iterable` but [`collections.abc.Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable).

So, either override the function [`is_atomic`](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/blob/master/gmaps/options.py#L34) right after importing `gmaps` :

```
def is_atomic(elem):
    return (
        isinstance(elem, string_types) or
        not isinstance(elem, collections.abc.Iterable) # <-- line updated
    )

gmaps.options.is_atomic = is_atomic
```

Or, update the source : `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gmaps/options.py` (*line 40*).